# Как изолировать содержимое виртуальной машины от провайдера?

Tags: безопасность, криптография, virtualbox, vps, виртуализация

Хочу попробовать арендовать дешевый и ненадежный vps в качестве хостинга для простого сервиса. Но провайдеру не доверяю, а сервис будет хранить некоторые данные. Есть ли способы изоляции данных от провайдера?
Если бы я узнал о том, как стоит к этому подойти, я мог бы арендовать самые подозрительные серверы без опасений за данные пользователей.

Провайдер может как минимум сделать копию виртуальной машины и потом, в тайне изучать данные или может сделать дамп памяти, вычисления же контролирует он. Вообще провайдер может даже подключить монитор и наблюдать за экраном моей машинки.
p.s. Если ты сейчас хочешь написать о том, что мои данные никому не нужны - уйди из вопроса прямо сейчас, меня не интересует чьё-то мнение по поводу целесообразности.

Я себе представляю какую-то систему с шифрованием, дамп которой не имел бы смысла, потому что по существу не предоставлял бы никаких полезных данных, как и мониторинг активности/вычислений.

Если решений не существует, но вы тоже об этом думали, опишите как вы себе представляете работу такой системы, условие только одно - машину физически контролирует провайдер, включая трафик. Если вы расшифровали что-то непосредственно на машине провайдера - он может сделать в этот момент снимок состояния машины и в любое время изучать расшифрованные в тот момент файлы.
Можете рассказать даже о безумно ресурсоёмких решениях вроде виртуальной машины с энтропией вычислений внутри. Интересно узнать обо всех достижениях человека в этой области.

Если вам интересно, я например наткнулся на [такую хабростатью](https://habr.com/post/315972/), но статья бессмысленная, в рамках условий описанных выше, потому что снимок системы в расшифрованном состоянии = компрометация машины

Comment: Вы собираетесь только загружать/раздавать/хранить на этой виртуалке  данные (файлы)? Тогда какие у вас требования к клиентскому софту?

Comment: @avp дело как раз в том, что меня интересуют секретные вычисления и работа с секретными данными на удаленной машине. Но сейчас я составил логическую схему задачи и не вижу возможностей это реализовать. В случае с хранением файлов все понятно - на удаленной машине хранятся данные только в зашифрованном виде, а расшифровывание, работа с секретными данными и секретные вычисления производятся клиентом. В этом случае сервер выступает в роли точки синхронизации и обмена зашифрованными данными между клиентами

Comment: Совершенно верно. Как только вы расшифруете данные в памяти они могут быть прочитаны провайдером. Найдет он их там  в самом деле или нет, зависит от его квалификации.

Comment: @avp пытаясь представить себе механизм, позволяющий производить секретные вычисления, я прихожу к виртуальной крипто-машине внутри машины провайдера. К такой машине, RAM которой была бы зашифрована, то есть физически представлена в не представляющем ценности виде. Которой можно было бы управлять через отведенный для этого интерфейс/порт, зная закрытый ключ. Которая при выполнении команд пользователя физически добавляла бы произвольные команды не имеющие отношения к текущей задаче, для предотвращения понимания реально выполняемых машиной действий. p.s. Под "физически", я имею в виду "для хоста"

Comment: Такую машину, которую можно было бы отключить/удалить, подсунуть ей свои данные, наблюдать за поведением, но нельзя было бы прочитать её память и понять важную ли команду она выполняет в текущий момент времени или запутывающую. Быстродействие такой машины было бы низким, но если бы это обеспечило безопасность, это стоило бы того

Comment: Не думаю, что на уровне виртуальной машины, исполняемой на известном хосте такую штуку можно сделать.

Comment: @avp почему? Интересны причины. Я не разбираюсь в работе процессора и памяти, возможно поэтому мне кажется теоретически возможным такой подход

Comment: Он возможен на реальном "криптожелезе". На виртуалке (или любом интерпретаторе) ничего полностью скрыть нельзя, потому что для конкретных вычислений вам нужно, чтобы реальные команды выполнялись. Т.е. при сложении, например, слагаемые должны быть в не зашифрованной форме. И т.д.